# How do you append 2 subnames to a variable in R?

Tags: r, list, variables

It has to be possible but I can't find an answer (or think of the proper search terms).

Basically I'm stuck in a double loop and need to append 2 different subnames (1 for each separate iteration) to a variable.

Basic example:

```
var <- list()
i1 <- 0
i2 <- 0

while (i1 < 3) {
i1 <- i1 - 1

while (i2 < 3) {
i2 <- i2 - 1

var[[i1]][[i2]] <- c(1, 5, 8)
}
}
```

However, stringing two subnames together like that doesn't seem to work.  I'd like to get 9 results (based on 3x3 iterations) names as var11, var12, var13, var21, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems as if you initialize i1 and i2 to 0, then proceed to subtract from them instead of add.  The above code will be an infinite loop, as i1 and i2 will always be negative, and therefore always less than 3

Comment: Oops, I meant to add 1 each iteration - not suptract one.  That was just a typo. :/

Comment: Wouldn't `lapply(1:3, function(i) paste0("var", 1:3, i))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you can do this in a simple one liner, but I'll initialize some variables to be explicit about it.

```
i1start<-1
i1end<-3
i2start<-1
i2end<-3
result<-lapply(i1start:i1end, function(i1) lapply(i2start:i2end, function(i2) c(1,5,8)))
```

Which should return a list of lists, where each entry at position (i1,i2) is the vector (1,5,8).

Let's break this down.  It'd be useful if you look up lapply (via the command ?lapply) to brush up on the function.

If we were to just run the inner lapply, what would happen?

```
 lapply(i2start:i2end, function(i2) c(1,5,8))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 5 8
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 5 8
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 5 8
```

lapply "applies" the vector 1,2,3 (i2start:i2end) to the function, which is essentially the following

```
#lapply does this
function(1) c(1,5,8)
function(2) c(1,5,8)
function(3) c(1,5,8)
```

and then stores all these results in a list (since it is **l**-apply)

We then use the same concept in the outer lapply call, except our function has changed.  It is no longer

```
 function(i) c(1,5,8)
```

but actually

```
 #substituting 1:3 for i2start:i2end
 function(i) lapply(1:3, function(i2) c(1,5,8))
```

so now we are calling

```
 lapply(1:3, function(i1) lapply(1:3, function(i2) c(1,5,8)))
```

which essentially calls

```
 function(1) lapply(1:3, function(i2) c(1,5,8))
 function(2) lapply(1:3, function(i2) c(1,5,8))
 function(3) lapply(1:3, function(i2) c(1,5,8))
```

and stores the results of those functions in a list.  Each of those function calls then run the inner function, which I explained just prior, and when you put it all together, it leads to your result!  A lot going on in one line

Comment: Thank you!  This does exactly what I need.  Although, I have to be honest, I don't entirely understand how it works - would you mind explaining what's happening in the last line of the code?  I'd love to learn how to do it properly myself instead of copy pasting something I don't understand. :D

Comment: Yeah sure thing!  I'll add the breakdown in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to initialize properly your `i1` and `i2` variables and increase them rather than decrease. Then, in the inner loop you initialize a sublist and assign that sublist to your `var` list. Try this:

```
    var <- list()
    i1 <- 0
    while (i1 < 3) {
      i2<-0
      i1 <- i1 + 1
      var2<-list()
      while (i2 < 3) {
        i2 <- i2 + 1
        var2[[i2]] <- sample(1:10,3)
      }  
    var[[i1]]<-var2
    }
```

Another approach could be initialize your principal list and all the sublists:

```
    var<-vector("list",3)
    for (i in 1:3) var[[i]]<-vector("list",3)
```

At this point, you can assign values with the double subscript:

```
    var[[i]][[j]]<-c(1,5,8)
```

Assuming that both i and j ranging from 1 to 3,

Comment: Thank you!  This also works exactly as needed.  Glad to have two approaches to the problem. :)